# Airflow DAGS are not running- Very new to Airflow and Docker

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am trying to run my Dag but it is failing saying error:

ERROR - [Errno 2] File b'C:/docker/docker-airflow-master/store_file/raw_store_transactions.csv' does not exist: b'C:/docker/docker-airflow-master/store_file/raw_store_transactions.csv'
Traceback (most recent call last):

I have file in this location.
below is the code for "docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml"

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
                
     mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.27
        environment:
            -MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        volumes:
            - ./store_file:/store_files_my_sql/
            - ./mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - mysql
        environment:
            - INSTALL_MYSQL=y
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            -./store_file:/usr/local/airflow/store_file_airflow
            -./sql_files:/usr/local/airflow/sql_files
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

code for Dag.py(below)

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from datacleaner import data_cleaner

default_args = {
    'owner':'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2022,12,14),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=10)
}

dag=DAG('store_dag',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval='@daily',catchup=False)

t2=PythonOperator(task_id='clean_raw_csv',python_callable=data_cleaner,dag=dag)
```

code for dataCleaner.py(below)

```
def data_cleaner():

    import pandas as pd
    

    df = pd.read_csv('C:/docker/docker-airflow-master/store_file/raw_store_transactions.csv')

    def check_null():
        df.isnull().sum()
        a = df.isnull().sum()
        a.to_csv('file.csv')
        return
    check_null()
```

Please help me with this error

Answer (score 0):

the airflow container does not have access to your host unless you bind volume.

I see that you mapped the "store_file" to `/usr/local/airflow/store_file_airflow` so the path to the file is `/usr/local/airflow/store_file_airflow/raw_store_transactions.csv`

Comment: hi your solution didn't worked, but thanks for trying

Comment: @BhanuKumar if you enter one of airflow container, can you find the file ? if so, you can understand the full path